# onKeyDown Event in React with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my React component I have the following input element:

```
  <input
    max={120}
    type="number"
    value={numValue}
    onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
  />
```

And this is my `handleKeyDown` function:

```
  const handleKeyDown = (evt: KeyboardEvent) => {
    console.log(evt.key);
    console.log(evt.target.value);
  }
```

And this is the error I get from TypeScript

```
Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

What is the event type I need to assign so that it covers both the `evt.target.value` and the `evt.key` ?

Comment: try it without evt: `KeyboardEvent`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are two issues:

The way you write your code prevents the TypeScript compiler to infer the type of the event's current target. You can either inline the function like this:

```
  <input max={120} type="number" value={numValue} onKeyDown={(evt) => {...}} />
```

or help the compiler out like this:

```
  const handleKeyDown = (evt: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {...}
```

But the problem won't go away, because, even if in this instance we are sure that `evt.target` is an instance of `HTMLInputElement`, we can't be in the general case. For instance, if your event handler was attached to a `<div>` with an `<input>` inside, the `div` could receive events where `evt.target` is not an `HTMLDivElement` but an `HTMLInputElement` because of event bubbling!

`evt.currentTarget` would achieve what you want. Or, in this particular case, a type assertion (`(evt.target as HTMLInputElement).value`) is also safe.

Comment: `KeyboardEvent` isn't generic, so `KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>` will not work

Comment: @DaveLunny native `KeyboardEvent` isn't, `React.KeyboardEvent` is.

Comment: Sorry I spoke too soon -- you are absolutely correct.

Comment: @DaveLunny Actually it is a legitimate point of confusion. I've updated the answer to use `React.KeyboardEvent` instead of `KeyboardEvent`. Thank you.

Answer (score -3):

You just need to make a little change in your function

```
const handleKeyDown = (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.key);
    console.log(evt.target.value);
    // set num value here
}
```

Comment: removing the typing? how is that a solution?